# How to get current segment .ts information of m3u8 standard playlist?

Tags: javascript, video.js, http-live-streaming, m3u8, fairplay

We are using **videojs.fairplay.js** for playing **DRM** content in MAC safari browser. At first while playing DRM video we get one standard playlist **(.m3u8)** that has defined stack of segments **(.ts)**.  We need to know the each segment information and there complete meta information like (length, type, url, etc..).

Answer (score 1):

```
var video = videojs("my-video");

video.on('playing', function () {
    console.log("The video has been playing");

    var segment = get_current_segment_info(this);
    console.log(segment.uri);
});

function get_current_segment_info(obj, old_segment = null) {
    var target_media = obj.tech().hls.playlists.media();
    var snapshot_time = obj.currentTime();

var segment;
var segment_time;

// Itinerate trough available segments and get first within which snapshot_time is
for (var i = 0, l = target_media.segments.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Note: segment.end may be undefined or is not properly set
    if (snapshot_time < target_media.segments[i].end) {
        segment = target_media.segments[i];
        break;
    }
}

// Null segment_time in case it's lower then 0.
if (segment) {
    segment_time = Math.max(0, snapshot_time - (segment.end - segment.duration));
    // Because early segments don't have end property
} else {
    segment = target_media.segments[0];
    segment_time = 0;
}
console.log(snapshot_time);
console.log(segment.uri);
console.log(segment.resolvedUri);
console.log(segment);
return segment;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some explanation for your answer, posting code only will not considered as a valid answer.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers